# What is a DeepWord™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **DeepWord™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Deep Words™ | Not Deep Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| SUB | SUN |
| PAY | PAN |
| RAW | PAW |
| SELF | MALE |
| FISH | ZONE |
| RARE | DEAR |
| TANG | SLAB |
| BLAIR | BOOKS |
| FEMALE | TIGERS |

Or, in a CSV:

```
Deep Words™,Not Deep Words™
SUB, SUN
PAY, PAN
RAW, PAW
SELF, MALE
FISH, ZONE
RARE, DEAR
TANG, SLAB
BLAIR, BOOKS
FEMALE, TIGERS
```

These are not the only examples of Deep Words™, more exist.

**What makes a Deep Word?**

**Bonus question:** There is also a word known as the Deepest Word™, why is this the case?

> Faun

Comment: Is the given Deepest Word™ the only one that exists? (As you said "There is also **a** word") Or could there be others too?

Comment: @Supersonic I have only been able to find a single word based on the rule

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A DeepWord™ is a word such that:

> When each letter is mapped to numbers using A1Z26 and added, the result is $42$.

A Deepest Word™ is a word such that:

> All letters mapped to numbers using A1Z26 are factors of $42$.

DeepWords™:

> SUB $\rightarrow 19+21+2=42$
>  PAY $\rightarrow 16+1+25=42$
>  SELF $\rightarrow 19+5+12+6=42$
>  BLAIR $\rightarrow 2+12+1+9+18=42$
>  FEMALE $\rightarrow 6+5+13+1+12+5=42$
>  FAUN $\rightarrow 6+1+21+14=42$ (also $1,6,14,21$ are all factors of $42$)

Not DeepWords™:

> SUN $\rightarrow 19+21+14=54$
>  PAN $\rightarrow 16+1+14=31$
>  PAW $\rightarrow 16+1+23=40$
>  ZONE $\rightarrow 26+15+14+5=60$
>  TIGERS $\rightarrow 20+9+7+5+18+19=78$

They are called DeepWords™ because:

> $42$ was computed as the *Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything* by the computer *DeepThought* in *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* book series.

Comment: One final point is the 42 is in relation to Deep-thought from Hitchhikers Guide, used to calculate the answer the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything

Comment: Well done, ill need to spend more time making it slightly tougher next time.

Comment: If this reasoning is correct for Deepest Word, wouldn't GUN also qualify? (7,14,21)

Comment: @Sconibulus - You may be correct.

Comment: Yep, it should qualify! But as OP didn't state that the reasoning is wrong and accepted too I think it is likely that they missed this word :)

Comment: @Sconibulus You are correct good sir